# Throwing ball against oily/slippery wall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, collision

I would like to know whether a ball bounces back normally if you throw it against an oily wall. Like a wall watered down with oil.
Basically I want to know if it will actually slip before bouncing back or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friction is always in the opposite direction of the movement of the object. If a ball rolls north on a floor, friction points south. For the ball to experience friction from the wall, it has to move along the wall. If the ball is thrown perpendicular to the wall it will not be moving along the wall, so it can't slip. However, if the ball is spinning, it *will* slip because the surface is moving along the wall.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. So from my understanding it will always bounce back normally regardless of whether the ball is hit against the wall with a right angle or not as long as there's no spin to the ball.

Comment: The ball will _not_ slip _only_ if the trajectory of the ball is perpendicular to the wall _and_ there is no spin.

Comment: This could be frustrating explaining to me but it will slip if the trajectory is not perpendicular, say you throw the ball with a slightly down slope trajectory, and there is no spin, right?

Comment: Correct. If the ball is moving slightly downwards it might slip.